# Image intervention not working after download, composer update not working. Earlier I deleted the vendor folder accidently

Tags: php, laravel, image, routes, intervention

[This image of composer update command not working][1]

[Following error occur while running the program][2]

```
web.php

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;


Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/image', function(){

    $img = ImageManagerStatic::make('images/altroz13.jpg')
                              ->resize(400, 250)
                              ->save('images/altroz13a.jpg');
});


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6Ad.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO7Bp.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

I Use
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic;

Now Its Working..